# Best practice for finding specific com port a USB device is connected to?

Tags: c#, serial-port, usb

I have a set of devices that all connect to a host PC. One of them is a bare metal processor running C code I wrote that includes a USB port that acts as a CDC device. This CPU enumerates as a COM port in windows. There are other USB based devices which show up as virtual COM ports connected to the same PC as part of the overall system. The PC communicates with all devices via a C# front end.

One issue I am having is I need a way to find my CPU's COM port among all other COM ports. My first thought was to send a "magic message" like Hello, and look for the device that sends back world. However, that risks potentially sending something to an unknown device that may respond in a bad way. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: you probablly want to query the ports via WMI to get the USB information

Comment: @KeithNicholas I am trying that. I am using the WMI code creator (on phone so no link) however I cannot seem to get some of the properties I might want. I can set the is device descriptor, so I can set the bus reported device value. I can see it in the properties of the device in the device manager but I cannot seem to programmatically pull the value. When I ask for the description it gives me a generic USB serial device